# How do I get an item from POJO classes in Android?

Tags: java, android, json, pojo

I am trying to get a specific Item from an API in my android application.
Here is the JSON response of the api:

```
{

    "response": {
        "items": [
            {
                "episode_id": 9599548,
                "type": "RECORDED",
                "title": "Adabule muferad 100916",
                "duration": 3165940,
                "explicit": false,
                "show_id": 1392538,
                "author_id": 7725967,
                "site_url": "https://www.spreaker.com/episode/9599548",
                "image_url": "https://d1bm3dmew779uf.cloudfront.net/large/f390b915e356de35055d971be5110dcb.jpg",
                "image_original_url": "https://d3wo5wojvuv7l.cloudfront.net/images.spreaker.com/original/f390b915e356de35055d971be5110dcb.jpg",
                "published_at": "2016-10-09 11:01:48",
                "download_enabled": true,
                "waveform_url": "https://d3770qakewhkht.cloudfront.net/episode_9599548.gz.json?v=qB6pQ6"
            }
        ],
        "next_url": "https://api.spreaker.com/v2/users/7725967/episodes?filter=listenable&last_id=9599548&limit=1"
    }

}
```

I have three Java classes Items, Response and RadioProgramInfo.
Here are their codes respectively:

Items.java

```
public class Items
{
    public String duration;
    public String title;
    public String download_enabled;
    public String image_original_url;
    public String image_url;
    public String explicit;
    public String episode_id;
    public String author_id;
    public String show_id;
    public String type;
    public String waveform_url;
    public String published_at;
    public String site_url;
    public String getDuration ()
    {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration (String duration)
    {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getTitle ()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle (String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDownload_enabled ()
    {
        return download_enabled;
    }

    public void setDownload_enabled (String download_enabled)
    {
        this.download_enabled = download_enabled;
    }

    public String getImage_original_url ()
    {
        return image_original_url;
    }

    public void setImage_original_url (String image_original_url)
    {
        this.image_original_url = image_original_url;
    }

    public String getImage_url ()
    {
        return image_url;
    }

    public void setImage_url (String image_url)
    {
        this.image_url = image_url;
    }

    public String getExplicit ()
    {
        return explicit;
    }

    public void setExplicit (String explicit)
    {
        this.explicit = explicit;
    }

    public String getEpisode_id ()
    {
        return episode_id;
    }

    public void setEpisode_id (String episode_id)
    {
        this.episode_id = episode_id;
    }

    public String getAuthor_id ()
    {
        return author_id;
    }

    public void setAuthor_id (String author_id)
    {
        this.author_id = author_id;
    }

    public String getShow_id ()
    {
        return show_id;
    }

    public void setShow_id (String show_id)
    {
        this.show_id = show_id;
    }

    public String getType ()
    {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType (String type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getWaveform_url ()
    {
        return waveform_url;
    }

    public void setWaveform_url (String waveform_url)
    {
        this.waveform_url = waveform_url;
    }

    public String getPublished_at ()
    {
        return published_at;
    }

    public void setPublished_at (String published_at)
    {
        this.published_at = published_at;
    }

    public String getSite_url ()
    {
        return site_url;
    }

    public void setSite_url (String site_url)
    {
        this.site_url = site_url;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [duration = "+duration+", title = "+title+", download_enabled = "+download_enabled+", image_original_url = "+image_original_url+", image_url = "+image_url+", explicit = "+explicit+", episode_id = "+episode_id+", author_id = "+author_id+", show_id = "+show_id+", type = "+type+", waveform_url = "+waveform_url+", published_at = "+published_at+", site_url = "+site_url+"]";
    }
}
```

Response.java

```
public class Response
{
    private Items[] items;

    private String next_url;

    public Items[] getItems ()
    {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems (Items[] items)
    {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public String getNext_url ()
    {
        return next_url;
    }

    public void setNext_url (String next_url)
    {
        this.next_url = next_url;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [items = "+items+", next_url = "+next_url+"]";
    }
}
```

RadioProgramInfo.java

```
public class RadioProgramInfo
{
    private Response response;

    public Response getResponse ()
    {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse (Response response)
    {
        this.response = response;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [response = "+response+"]";
    }
}
```

I am trying to access a specific Item called "site_url" which is located in Items.java

The code in my main class to try to access site_url is this:

```
Items url2 = new Items();
    String streamURL = String.valueOf(url2)+"/shoutcast?force_http=true";

//    new HttpRequestTask().execute();
//    return true;

    String url = "http://api.spreaker.com/listen/episode/9451446/shoutcast?force_http=true";
    //String url2 = Items.class.getName(site_url);

    public MainActivity() {

    }


    //System.out.println(streamURL);


    public class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Items> {

        protected Items doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                final String url = String.valueOf(streamURL);
                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                //restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
                Items streamlink = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Items.class);
                return streamlink;
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            return url2;
        }
    }
```

When I run my program (a media player app):
It tells me that the url is null in value (I debug mode on the program as it executes).

How do I correctly access the item in the JSON response I am after?
I am really stuck on this one.

---UPDATE-----
Here is the response from the console:

```
10-09 15:25:39.522 2586-2647/software.blackstone.com.salafimasjidradioseries E/MainActivity: 'messageConverters' must not be empty
                                                                                             java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'messageConverters' must not be empty
                                                                                                 at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:269)
                                                                                                 at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.<init>(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:53)
                                                                                                 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:235)
                                                                                                 at software.blackstone.com.salafimasjidradioseries.MainActivity$HttpRequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:46)
                                                                                                 at software.blackstone.com.salafimasjidradioseries.MainActivity$HttpRequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:39)
                                                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

.... and the complete MainActivity Code is this:

```
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.io.IOException;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    ImageButton buttonPlay;
    ImageButton buttonStop;

    Items url2 = new Items();
    String streamURL = String.valueOf(url2)+"/shoutcast?force_http=true";

//    new HttpRequestTask().execute();
//    return true;

    String url = "http://api.spreaker.com/listen/episode/9451446/shoutcast?force_http=true";
    //String url2 = Items.class.getName(site_url);

    public MainActivity() {

    }


    //System.out.println(streamURL);


    public class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Items> {

        protected Items doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                final String url = String.valueOf(streamURL);
                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                //restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
                Items streamlink = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Items.class);
                return streamlink;
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(), e);
            }

            return url2;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        new HttpRequestTask().execute();
    }
```

Comment: Cant really help you with spring, but... why are you using spring for this? are you using it somewhere else? otherwise, try Gson?

Comment: @damian I am willing to use Okhttp, Gson, Spring or whatever I can that is easy to integrate and get the job done. I am stumbling on this badly.

Comment: I've posted it as an answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i admittedly don't have any experience using Spring libraries for mobile development. there are, however, several other popular libraries at your disposal that are typically used to accomplish your goal.

below is an example i whipped using your DTO classes. i added these dependencies via my app's `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
```

- OkHttp is a library for creating + executing HTTP requests
- Gson is a library for (un)marshaling data as json

the code should be pretty self-explanatory. i've just plugged in the bits to do my HTTP GET and marshal the data into the DTO within the AsyncTask.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    private OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    public class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Items[]> {
        protected Items[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
            final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1z98u")
                .build();

            Items[] items = null;

            try {
                final com.squareup.okhttp.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    final RadioProgramInfo radioProgramInfo = gson.fromJson(response.body().charStream(), RadioProgramInfo.class);

                    items = radioProgramInfo.getResponse().getItems();

                } else {
                    throw new RuntimeException("ooops!");
                }

            } catch (Throwable t) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", t.getMessage(), t);
            }

            return items;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Items[] items) {
            try {
                mPlayer.setDataSource(items[0].getSite_url());
                mPlayer.prepareAsync();

            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });

        new HttpRequestTask().execute();
    }

}
```

hope that helps!

Comment: additionally, depending on your needs, you might look into using a REST library like Retrofit (as mentioned by @damian) or Volley. as always, the right tool for the job depends on what your needs are.

Comment: @hsi the line "return items;" throw an incompatible type error.

Comment: take note of the difference between the parameterized type declarations in our `HttpRequestTask` definitions (`Items` vs `Items[]`). i did this because `Response` has a collection of `Items` (presumably because the API can return more than one `Items` per request?) if the task should not return more than one item, you can either 1) modify `Response` to only contain a single `Items` type, or 2) return a single `Items` from the task itself.. while leaving the rest of your code intact. otherwise, if more than one `Items` can be expected, modify your task to return a collection of `Items`.

Comment: @hsi ithanks for the update. I actually changed found that out not too long after I posted my message to you. I am trying to get the site_url which is in the Items class. I need that to feed into the mPlayer.setDataSource line in the Main class. I can't access it (I actually can't figure out how)??

Comment: i updated my sample code. i've demonstrated two ways set the `MediaPlayer` data source. 1) you could override `HttpRequestTask.onPostExecute()` to interrogate site_url from the response and use it to set the data source, or 2) you could do the same from the point where you create and execute the task in `MainActivity.onCreate()`. (i think i prefer #1). keep in mind though, since your DTOs accommodate for an array of `Items`, i'm just sort of blindly choosing the first one.

Comment: @hsi thanks again. I keep getting on the line "mPlayer.setDataSource(items[0].getSite_url());" a null error.
When I run a debug session on it, it steps into Items.java correctly and I get the site_url correctly. but calling it in Main gives a null error.

Comment: one of these things is null: `mPlayer`, `items`, `items` may be initialized but empty, or possibly even the the site_url value itself maybe null. have you tried setting some break points in your code to evaluate each of these things?

Comment: @hsi yes I have added breakpoints. Its the actual player itself ... it is giving me a player not ready error. But the debug trace says that the url I want to play s correct so far.\

Comment: see my latest changes. per the api docs, if you're loading a remote data source for the `MediaPlayer` you should start it asynchronously via an `OnPreparedListener` due to the latency involved in having to fetch and possibly decode the data. in `onCreate()` i'm now setting an `OnPreparedListener` for this purpose. in `HttpRequestTask.onPostExecute()` the datasource is set based on the result of the call, and the `MediaPlayer` is invoked to prepare for playback via `prepareAsync()`.

Comment: This solution actually works like a charm!! I changed my approach a little bit and extracted the episodeID and constructed the URL with a dynamic episode ID and my app now works beautifullly with no issues!!

Comment: @hsi it was very cool actually!! I was able to even make a selector around the solution as well to choose where to pull the stream from! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Since youre not really sure what to use and are currently using Spring, I'd recommend you to take a look at [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) which does exactly what you are looking for. It has very good documentation and a lot of examples of exactly what you're trying to do.. Here's a pretty good introduction to it: [square.github.io/retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)